# Estimated number of balls of certain type to be picked

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Lets say there are 100 balls in a box. 10 of them are of certain type (Say Red). If 10 balls are selected at random, how can i calculate the average or estimated number of Red balls in this selection?

Does this formula hold true when the scenario is slightly modified: 100 balls are first divided into ten sets, one set is selected at random, a.k.a 10 balls of this set are selected.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I dont know if im missing something, but its clear to me that given a 10% chance of a ball being red, the estimated number of balls being red in a set of 10  balls is 10% out of 10 that is 1 red ball. Also the second scenario seems to me exactly like the first one ( note that the chance of a ball being red doesnt chance) .

Comment: Assume you mean selected at random without replacement, you can take a look at the hypergeometric distribution. For the second part: It does not matter.